# Frontend assests have no base url

Tags: magento-1, javascript, frontend

We have a strange issue on one of our live websites.
Every now and then the websites frontend assets don't load. By looking at the paths it's trying to load it is because the base part of the URL is missing. e.g.

```
<script src="/js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

All data shows just not JS/CSS. Any idea's why this could be?

Answer (score 0):

navigate to **system->configuration->General->web**
and check the following settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response but it's not that. I've checked the usual suspects caching etc etc.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%merge%'  use this sql on your DB and if values are 1 then make it 0 and clear cache. This might be the issue.